# How do I parse maximum number of a formated div value? BS4

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to create a parser for a website that uses pseudo-table view application. Question is how to parse `cid` that is formated in specific manner.

`cid` have two formated variables `R (row)` and `C (column)`. For example `cid="R1C1"` means row №1 and column №1 in the data. I want to get the maximum value of rows. So in this case 99.

Data Example

```
<div align="center" ccnt="1" cid="R1C1"><div rid="v"><span rv="1">1</span></div></div>
<div align="center" ccnt="1" cid="R1C2"><div rid="v"><span rv="1970">1970</span></div></div>
<div ccnt="1" cid="R1C3"><div rid="v">No Name</div></div>
<div ccnt="1" cid="R1C4"><div rid="v">New York</div></div>

...

<div align="center" ccnt="1" cid="R99C1"><div rid="v"><span rv="99">99</span></div></div>
<div align="center" ccnt="1" cid="R99C2"><div rid="v"><span rv="2020">2020</span></div></div>
<div ccnt="1" cid="R99C3"><div rid="v">No Name</div></div>
<div ccnt="1" cid="R99C4"><div rid="v">Iraq</div></div>
```

I do not know how to handle this. I could use list comprehension to strip and parse all the digit values and write them up in the list and get then maximum value of the list but in this case it wont work. There is a lot of external digits in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `soup.find_all()` with custom regex in `cid=` parameter and then combine it with `max()` function.

For example:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<div align="center" ccnt="1" cid="R1C1"><div rid="v"><span rv="1">1</span></div></div>
<div align="center" ccnt="1" cid="R1C2"><div rid="v"><span rv="1970">1970</span></div></div>
<div ccnt="1" cid="R1C3"><div rid="v">No Name</div></div>
<div ccnt="1" cid="R1C4"><div rid="v">New York</div></div>

<div align="center" ccnt="1" cid="R99C1"><div rid="v"><span rv="99">99</span></div></div>
<div align="center" ccnt="1" cid="R99C2"><div rid="v"><span rv="2020">2020</span></div></div>
<div ccnt="1" cid="R99C3"><div rid="v">No Name</div></div>
<div ccnt="1" cid="R99C4"><div rid="v">Iraq</div></div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

r = re.compile(r'R(\d+)C\d+')
max_row = max(int(r.search(div['cid']).group(1)) for div in soup.find_all(cid=r))
print(max_row)
```

Prints:

```
99
```

Comment: @harryhow `re.search(r'R(\d+)C\d+', some_text).group(1)` will get the first `()` group, in this case `(\d+)` which are digits after R character.

Answer (score 0):

If you know number of columns then you can just count the divs which has cid attributes (meaning all divs representing table ) and divide it by number of columns

Or you could do these

```py
    def getRowNo(cid):
        '''
        R99C3.split('C') => ['R99', '3' ] 
        ['R99', '3' ][0][1:]  => '99'
        '''
        return int(cid.split('C')[0][1:])

    rownos = [ getRowNo(div['cid'] ) for div in soup.find_all( 'div', cid=True)] 

    Max_row = max(rownos)
```